# Swift Compiler Error Expected expression in list of expressions

Tags: swift

I have an error when using swift syntax:

[image]

```
public func successor() -> JSONIndex {
    switch self.type {
    case .array:
        return JSONIndex(arrayIndex: (self.arrayIndex! + 1))
    case .dictionary:
        return JSONIndex(dictionaryIndex: <#T##Dictionary corresponding to your index##Dictionary<<#Key: Hashable#> Any>#>.index(after: self.dictionaryIndex!))
    default:
        return JSONIndex()
    }
}
```

Comment: How did this "code": `<#T##Dictionary corresponding to your index##Dictionary<<#Key: Hashable#> Any>#>` get in there? It seems you're pasting in code from a tutorial that expects you to fill in placeholders with the correct values, and you haven't bothered.

Comment: i have converted my app to courent swift syntax is not from a tutorial

Comment: Interesting. Then the conversion process is buggy. By not putting that as context in the question, you made it slower to answer. Please add that and show the original Swift 1.0 or 2.0 code. It should be clear that a string of descriptive English words is not Swift syntax in the first place, but you didn't mention that observation.

Comment: Then the original swift never compiled. Do you think it did?

Comment: One could reasonably guess that it should say: `return JSONIndex(dictionaryIndex: (self. dictionaryIndex! + 1))` Any reason you didn't try that, based on visual pattern matching? Is the code just not familiar to you?

Comment: that's the original swift   
http://agourdaffiliate.us/Json/SwiftyJSON.swift

Comment: i tray it but it bug 16 error in the app no this app not familar for me

Comment: There are bigger issues. You should not be using an old version of SwiftyJSON and trying to get it to update to swift 3 syntax. You should be installing the newest Swift 3 compatible release of SwiftyJSON. Whatever is preventing you from doing this is the real problem.

Comment: So ther  is no solution

Comment: I just gave you the solution.

Comment: yeah thanx broth